# How to use async / await in Chrome or Edge mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I've completed my first JavaScript course and am now following a course on React. I've created a simple backend using Express and MongoDB.

I've created a frontend using npx create-react-app, added axios to communicate with the backend and am using antd for the UI. So far so good! The following code works on my laptop running Windows 10 and Edge 94 to insert a new Year into MongoDB using a simple input:

Client uses:

```
  const onFinish = async (values) => {
    await api.createYear(values).then((res) => {
      console.log("onFinish", values);
      console.log(res);
    });
  };
```

API uses:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1',
})

export const createYear = values => api.post(`/year`, values)
```

Server (controller) uses:

```
const Year = require('../models/year-model')

createYear = (req, res) => {
    const body = req.body
    if (!body) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            error: 'You must provide a year!',
        })
    }
    const year = new Year(body)
    if (!year) {
        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
    }
    year
        .save()
        .then(() => {
            return res.status(201).json({
                success: true,
                id: year._id,
                message: 'Year created!',
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error,
                message: 'Year not created!',
            })
        })
}
```

Server (model) uses:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const yearSchema = new Schema(
    {
        year: { type: Number, required: true }
    },
    { timestamps: false },
)

module.exports = mongoose.model('Year', yearSchema)
```

However, the same code does not work on my Samsung Galaxy S21 using Edge 93 and Chrome 94. Based on what I found so far, this could be caused by this browser not supporting async/await (ES2017 feature). This could probably be resolved by Babel?

I'm sorry that this part is pretty vague: the information I found is a kind of overwhelming considering my limited experience and all variables involved (React version, Babel version, Babel plugins, Webpack etc). I would gladly provide more information if you could point me in the right direction.

Could anyone perhaps tell me if and how I should change Babel or Webpack to make async/await work in mobile browsers?

Comment: How did you test your code on your mobile browser? Through network IP, right? And how are you connecting your front-end with the back-end?
It's not a mobile browser issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that async/await doesn't work on those browsers, then I think you can change your `.babelrc` file to target older browsers.

However, to address @ammar's points, maybe double check that:

- you can see web pages served by your laptop on your phone
- your phone browser doesn't work with async/await

I would create a simple html page that looks like this to make sure that this is the problem.

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div>TEST PAGE<div>
    <div id='test'></div>
    <script>
      function sleep(t) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            setTimeout(resolve, t);
        });
      }


      (async function() {
          for (let x = 0; x < 1000; x++) {
             document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = x;
             await sleep(1000);
          }
      })();
    </script>
  <body>
</html>
```

I would attack it like this:

- save the above as `test.html`
- open the file directly with your laptop browser and see the count-up
- figure out how to serve the same file as static content with the webpack dev server, and open it in the laptop browser
- open the same file on your mobile device to prove that you can see the page at all, and that async/await is not working

Comment: Hi Ammar and Alex, thank you for the replies. I need to figure out how to serve index.html using Webpack. I ran a quick test by using my 'Go Live' development server and the count up did work on my mobile device. So I guess the problem is specific to Babel/Webpack in create-react-app, so I'll try and serve index.html from there.

Comment: Hi all, I've created a new app using 'npx create-react-app axios-test' and replaced the contents of public\index.html with the contents of index.html from @Alex028502 (and added '<div id="root"></div>' since it's a React app). The count up is visible in Edge on my phone. Could it be the 'await' that's causing the problem?

Comment: the count up depends on await, so if that works on your phone, the problem isn't that your phone can't use await I guess

Comment: I mean.. to say the same thing with fewer double negatives - if the count up works, async/await works... so that isn't the problem you are looking for

Comment: The code you pasted above... is that from the client or the server?

Comment: Hi @Alex028502, original code was from the client. I added the code from API and server.  I can't really figure out why this does work on PC and doesn't work on phone.

Comment: If possible, I would try it on a second laptop, to find out if you can make it work over the network at all.. and then... if it doesn't work, at least you can look at the browser's network tab on the client laptop and see which call is being blocked, or if there are console errors, since that is harder to see on a phone.  Or do you have browser dev tools set up for your mobile devices?

Comment: Thanks @Alex028502, your last message helped me solve the problem. I feel kind of stupid... I thought the API code was called locally on my developer laptop, but apparently this gets called from the actual client.. I tried a second laptop and noticed it tried to open http://localhost:3000/api/v1. Changing the axios base URL to the actual IP address of my developer laptop solved the problem!